# How is java platform independent if I need different JVM for different system?

Tags: java, c, operating-system, compiler-construction

Just like how we need to download different C compiler for different Systems, We need to download different JVM for different System. So, how is java platform independent ?

Comment: The author of a Java application can distribute the same compiled bytecode to be deployed on different platforms.

Comment: This [article](https://medium.com/@neil.wilston123/why-java-is-platform-independent-1d82c2249a69) can also explain it. Although @dbush explained it nicely.

Comment: JVM Is a "runtime", and those are intractably platform-dependent. The code, however, like JavaScript, is portable.

Answer (score 3):

The Java language is platform independent because a particular piece of code is guaranteed to run the same on any system it is executed on.

While there may be a different JVM for each system, all JVMs are required to run the same Java bytecode the same way.